# Error in x[seq_len(n)] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable

Tags: r, error-handling, lme4, mixed-models

I have a very simple code but still get this error. How can I solve it? It occurs after the `view` command at the end. When I run the commands one by one, there is no error until `view`.

```
library(haven)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

data <- read_sav("C:/Users/theot/Desktop/project_a/project_2/data.sav")
data_long <- pivot_longer(data,
                          cols = c(depres_1, depres_2),
                          names_to = "time", values_to = "depression")
dl <- data_long[, c("id", "group", "time", "depression", 
                    "ruminati")]
model <- lmer(depression ~ ruminati + time*group + (1|id), data=dl)
view(model)
```

Comment: Try `summary(model)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** try `summary(model)` as @RuiBarradas suggests in a comment.

Your example isn't reproducible, but I can make one that is:

```r
library(tibble)
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
view(fm1)
```

The `view()` function is a wrapper for the `View()` function in base R. If we try `View()` we get a different (slightly more comprehensible) error:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x) :
> cannot coerce class ‘structure("lmerMod", package = "lme4")’ to a data.frame

From `?View`:

> Invoke a spreadsheet-style data viewer on a **matrix-like** R object

(emphasis added): "matrix-like" means a data frame, matrix, tibble, etc. — i.e. a rectangular data set *that can be converted to a data frame*.

You can see the results of a fitted model by just printing it (`fm1` or `print(fm1)`) or running `summary(fm1)`. You might want to take a look at the `tidy` function in the `broom.mixed` package as well.